Hibernate 6 elementcollection fetching issue
I have following entities:
Template:
@Entity
@Data
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@Slf4j
public class Template implements ReportBlueprint {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR)
private UUID id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Source> sources = new LinkedList<>();

Source:
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Source {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR)
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Queries queries;

Queries:
@Entity
@Data
public class Queries {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR)
private UUID id;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<String> countries;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<String> series;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<String> years;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<String> vins;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<String> excluded;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<String> types;

After migrating from Spring Boot 2.6 to 3.3.5, the string sets (years,types,...) under the Queries entity aren't loaded, when i fetch the root Template entity with the JPARepository. In the old version it was loaded correctly.It finds the queries but each query have empty sets for these attributes.
I have compared the hibernate output of both versions and they seem to be similar:
2.6:
2.6:
select

        years0_."queries_id" as queries_1_82_0_,

        years0_."years" as years2_82_0_ 

    from

        "queries_years" years0_ 

    where

        years0_."queries_id" in (

            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?

        )

3.3.5:
select
        y1_0."queries_id",
        y1_0."years"
    from
        "queries_years" y1_0
    where
        y1_0."queries_id" = any (?)

any ideas? the query seems to be correct and the entities are in the database but the sets are empty.
